# Получить часовой пояс пользователя на стороне пользователя по Москве

Tags: javascript

Надо получить часовой пояс относительно Москвы, а не Гринвича, как это можно сделать)?

Comment: "часовой пояс относительно Москвы" - это что-то типа "глобуса России"?

Comment: Нет, это чтот тип var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

Comment: А в чем вообще сложность? Московский `TimezoneOffset` -180, Новосибирский например -420, Вам нужно 240? Я просто не понимаю в чем сложность?

Comment: Дак сложность в том,  что зимнее и летнее Гринвича и Москвы, или они не меняют?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var moscow_offset = -3 * 60; // 3 часа отступ по Гринвичу 
var user_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // текущий отступ пользователя
var offset = user_offset + Math.abs(moscow_offset); // смещение 0 на -3 часа 

console.log(moscow_offset, user_offset, offset)
```